# How to support the partial word search without NGramTokenizerFactory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr

My Rails application version is 2.3.11 and I am using acts_as_solr for search.
Search is working fine. My problem is it does not supports partial word search.

```
"success"
=>Getting search results
"succ"
=>No results
```

I have found that NGramTokenizerFactory can do that.But it requires to change the solr configuration file schema.xml.

Is there any other alternative solution to support partial word search without changing the solr configuration?

OR

Is there any solr query logic which supports the partial word search?

I have tried adding "succ*" it gives correct result.But still I am not able to search like "*word*".

Answer (score 1):

To use * at the beginning of the word you might need to add [ReversedWildcardFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory) to your schema

Comment: Thank you friend for your response.But it also requires to change the the schema.xml file.

Comment: Yes, to adjust Solr to work for you as you wish, you have to change your schema. The only other way, witch is more painful would be to do your string alteration during/before indexing time. But I believe that is not in Solr spirit. I'm very interested in how you would solve it. Btw, why can't you change your schema?